# Plot Multiple Coords on Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I need to plot multiple markers on a google map and am having trouble placing more than one marker.

This works:
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=26.549431,-81.847559

This does not:
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=26.549431,-81.847559&q=26.549579,-81.847757

Is there a way to send two coordinates to the Google Maps and return two markers?

Comment: there is no such option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using staticmap in the Google Map API did the trick:  http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=9&size=640x480&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=label:1|26.785,-82.045&markers=label:2|26.651,-82.0&markers=label:3|26.7,-81.75634&markers=label:4|26.6,-81.89&markers=label:5|26.475,-81.79&markers=label:6|26.41,-81.76&markers=label:7|26.42,-81.78&markers=label:8|26.43,-81.80&markers=label:9|26.44,-81.82&markers=label:10|26.45,-81.84&sensor=false